# How to set LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 for Godot on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, godot

I have a google colab notebook with the following code, where I am trying to use the avalon benchmark (https://github.com/Avalon-Benchmark/avalon):

```
!git clone https://github.com/Avalon-Benchmark/avalon.git

!pip install avalon-rl==1.0.0

!python -m avalon.install_godot_binary

import pathlib as pathlib
import shutil

from avalon.agent.godot.godot_gym import AvalonEnv
from avalon.agent.godot.godot_gym import GodotEnvironmentParams
from avalon.agent.godot.godot_gym import TrainingProtocolChoice
from avalon.datagen.env_helper import display_video
from avalon.datagen.world_creation.constants import AvalonTask
from avalon.datagen.world_creation.world_generator import GenerateAvalonWorldParams
from avalon.datagen.world_creation.world_generator import generate_world


env_params = GodotEnvironmentParams(
resolution=256,
training_protocol=TrainingProtocolChoice.SINGLE_TASK_FIGHT,
initial_difficulty=0,

)
env = AvalonEnv(env_params)
```

This code throws the error `Godot Engine v3.4.4.stable.avalon.e462a8744 https://godotengine.org ERROR: Error initializing GLAD at: is_viable (drivers/gles3/rasterizer_gles3.cpp:141) Your video card driver does not support any of the supported OpenGL versions. Please update your drivers or if you have a very old or integrated GPU, upgrade it. Alternatively, you can force software rendering by running Godot with the` LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 `environment variable set, but this will be very slow.`

I am not sure how to set this variable but I tried adding a cell before this code:

```
import os
os.environ['LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE']='1'
!export | grep LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE
```

But I am getting the same error message

Comment: I am running into the same issue; I am using the GPUs provided by Colab